# How to write several implementation of the same method that have a different signature

Tags: go, interface

I have several implementation of the same method `SetRateForMeasure`:

```
package repartition

type Repartition interface {
    Name() string
    Compute(meters []models.Meter, totalsProd, totalsConso map[string]float64) []models.Meter
    SetRateForMeasure(meter models.Meter, measure models.Measure, total float64) float64
}
```

Then, in my code (in repartition.go), I call it:

```
rate := repartition.SetRateForMeasure(meter, measure, total)
```

where repartition is the interface defined before.

Thing is, when I add a new implementation of this method, the arguments of my functions might differ.

For example, the static repartition use a static percentage that is only used in this case.

I end up adding parameters so that I have a common interface to all methods, but it results that there is a lot of unused parameters depending on the implementation.

If I add it to common interface, it will be unused for the other definitions.

I tried to remove this method from my interface definition, but now

```
rate := repartition.SetRateForMeasure()
```

is no more defined.

How should I organize my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no function overloading in Go, so you cannot declare the same function with different arguments. There's a few ways you can implement this though:

- You can add multiple functions with different names and signatures
- You can change the function to accept a struct instead of arguments

```
SetRateForMeasure(args SetRateOptions) float64

type SetRateOptions struct {
 Meter models.Meter
 Measure models.Measure
 Total float64
 Percentage *float64 // If nil, use default percentage
 ... // more parameters as needed
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see, I wouldn't add multiple functions, as all those functions do the same thing. I think it is coherent that they have the same name. I will go with struct param ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Go doesn't support method overriding. You either ​define methods with different names that take different parameters
​ or you can declare the method to accept a parameter struct.

```
type SetRateParams struct {
    Meter    models.Meter
    Measure  models.Measure
    Total    float64
}

type Repartition interface {
    SetRateForMeasure(params SetRateParams) float64
}
```

Optionally, you can declare params in your structs as pointers, so you can represent "not-provided" semantics with `nil` instead of using the zero-value. This might be relevant in case of numerical params where `0` could be a valid value.

Using a struct param has also the advantage that you don't have to change all the call sites in case you decide to add an additional param 6 months from now (you just add it to the struct).

There are also worse solutions with `interface{}` varargs, for the sake of stating what is possible, but unless you loathe type safety, I wouldn't recommend that.